# JPA mapping to Oracle user defined types

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Oracle allows for the definition of user defined types. Hibernate can map to these types using the org.hibernate.usertype.UserType class. This defines a mapping between a java bean and the Oracle type.

Using straight JPA, how would one do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with straight JPA. It doesn't have concept of user defined type. For this need you have to use vendor extensions.

Comment: Is that correct? I have found this link to the EclipseLink project which gives examples which appear to show it being done - my issue however is that I cannot find any class matching the @Struct annotation.

Comment: Sorry - here is the link I referred to:

Comment: ... Just to make it clear, the question is, in which jar is this class?

Comment: That is correct. You found vendor extension in EclipseLink project. Still it holds true, that you cannot do it with "straight JPA".

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Struct is for example in eclipselink-2.3.0.jar But originally you wanted to do something with plain JPA and this is something else.