# Oracle database object type import in JPA

Tags: jpa, oracle-objects

Is there a way to import oracle defined object type in JPA. I have a complex object defined in database :

```
create or replace TYPE "myType"{
someString varchar2(100),
someString2 varchar2(100),
constructor....}
```

this object type is than used in a database table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823855/jpa-mapping-to-oracle-user-defined-types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA mapping to Oracle user defined types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823855/jpa-mapping-to-oracle-user-defined-types)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard support for object-types in JPA.

If you are using EclipseLink, you can use the @Struct annotation to map object-types,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_struct.htm#CBBDCAHG

If you are mapped a table of the type, and the type has no nested types, then it will just look like a normal relational table, and you can just map in like a normal relational table.